# T-SQL Stored Procedure: Performance of select count(*) vs. select count([uniqueId])

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, stored-procedures

So, I'm looking at a stored procedure here, which has more than one line like the following pseudocode:

```
if(select count(*) > 0)
...
```

on tables having a unique id (or identifier, for making it more general).

Now, in terms of performance, is it more performant to change this clause 
to

```
if(select count([uniqueId]) > 0)
    ...
```

where uniqueId is, e.g., an `Idx` containing double values?

An example:

Consider a table like Idx (double) | Name (String) | Address (String)

Now the 'Idx' is a foreign key which I want to join in a stored procedure.

So, in terms of performance: what is better here?

```
if(select count(*) > 0)
    ...
```

or

```
if(select count(Idx) > 0)
    ...
```

? Or does the SQL Engine Change `select count(*)` to `select count(Idx)` internally, so we do not have to bother about this? Because at first sight, I'd say that `select count(Idx)` would be more performant.

Comment: For performance use `IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ...)` instead of counting. As about your question: query optimizer is smart enough to get the same optimal plan from `COUNT(1) vs COUNT(*) vs COUNT(index)`

Comment: ah okay, thank you! But nevertheless, I'll let this question open for i'm interested in an answer.

Comment: @lad2025 they will generate same execution plans. So Dominik use any of you provided or exists.

Comment: @lad2025 though sometimes the `count` can be optimised to not count all rows. See Adam Machanics comment here http://sqlblog.com/blogs/andrew_kelly/archive/2007/12/15/exists-vs-count-the-battle-never-ends.aspx

Comment: @MartinSmith, interesting link but there he uses where clause that I think has impact on? I have checked 4 variations with counts and exists and they are producing same plans and IO. And the link is old enought from 2007. I think optimizers got more clever since then?

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri I'm not sure of the exact circumstances where the optimisation can be applied. I'd always use `exists` to be sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two are slightly different. `count(*)` counts rows. `count([uniqueid])` counts the number of non-NULL values for `uniqueid`. Because a unique constraint allows a `NULL` value, SQL Server actually needs to read the column. This could add microseconds of time to a query, particularly if the page with the `id` is not already in memory. This also gives SQL Server more opportunities to optimize `count(*)`.

As @lad2025 writes in a comment, the performant solution is to use `if (exists . . .`.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM Table1 t1
JOIN Table2 t2 ON t2.idx = t1.idx
```

will give you only the rows in t1 that match an idx value in Table2. I'm not sure there is a good reason to do an if(select count...).

If you are really interested in the performance of something like this, just create a temp table with a million rows and give it a go:

```
CREATE TABLE #TempTable (id int identity, txt varchar(50))
GO

INSERT #TempTable (txt) VALUES (@@IDENTITY)
GO 1000000
```

Comment: `If` is a procedural keyword in TSQL. The OP will be using it against a result set such as a whole table not individual rows hopefully. And the is no indication that a second table is involved.